# MultiIndex names when using pd.concat disappeared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1: 
sim_names       Model 1          
signal_names     my_y1     my_y2
units               °C       kPa
(Time, s)                       
0.0           0.738280  1.478617
0.1           1.078653  0.486527
0.2           0.794123  0.604792
0.3           0.392690  1.072772 

df2: 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

As you see, `df1` has three levels with names `"sim_names", "signal_names" and "units"`.

Next, I want to concatenate the two dataframes, and therefore I run the following command:

```
    df2 = pd.concat(
        [df1, df2],
        axis="columns",
    )
```

but what I get is the following:

```
 df2:
             Model 1          
              my_y1     my_y2
                 °C       kPa
(Time, s)                    
0.0        0.738280  1.478617
0.1        1.078653  0.486527
0.2        0.794123  0.604792
0.3        0.392690  1.072772
```

As you see, the levels names are gone.

What should I do to keep the levels names of `df1` in the resulting `df2`?

My wanted resulting `df2` should be like the following:

```
df2: 
sim_names       Model 1          
signal_names     my_y1     my_y2
units               °C       kPa
(Time, s)                       
0.0           0.738280  1.478617
0.1           1.078653  0.486527
0.2           0.794123  0.604792
0.3           0.392690  1.072772
```

I tried to pass `names=["sim_names", "signal_names", "units"]` as argument to `pd.concat` but I got the same wrong result as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but seems like this is the normal behaviour (see [*GH13475*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13475#issuecomment-232310977)).

As a workaround, you can use [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)/[`names`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.names.html) :

```
out = pd.concat(
        [df1, df2],
        axis="columns",
    ).rename_axis(df1.columns.names, axis=1) # <- added chain
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

sim_names    Model 1      
signal_names   my_y1 my_y2
units             °C   kPa
(Time, s)                 
0.00            0.74  1.48
0.10            1.08  0.49
0.20            0.79  0.60
0.30            0.39  1.07
```

Comment: There we go, thanks! I think it is normal behaviour from pandas 2.0.1. Until yesterday I used pandas 1.5.x and my script was working fine. I don't think your proposal is a workaround but an actual solution.